# CNContactPickerViewController UI change for multi selection of contacts

Tags: ios, iphone, cncontactviewcontroller

For multiple contact selection in `CNContactPickerViewController`,i am using `delegate` method `didSelectContacts`, After implementing this `delegate` method user have a option to select multi contacts. By default it is showing radio button selection, but i need check marks selection, is there any way to change `UI` of user selection in `CNContactPickerViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still pertinent, but I would suggest using a contact picker clone such as https://github.com/JettF/JFContactsPicker (this one already has checkmarks.)